# Compiling LuaJit 2 for Android on mac. Assembler errors : lj_vm.s:5: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.private_extern'

Tags: android, assembly, android-ndk, luajit

Please advise about building android LuaJit on mac or tips on resolving `pseudo-op: '.private_extern'` assembler errors in general.

I am on Mac and following instruction to complie LuaJit2 in doc/install  or http://luajit.org/install.html#android :

The only change I made is to change `linux-x86` to `darwin-x86` to get `NDK` cross-compiler. I also added `TARGET_SYS=Linux` (I tried with and without) per installation notes: “Whenever the host OS and the target OS differ, you need to specify `TARGET_SYS` or you'll get assembler or linker errors…”

So my build script looks like this:

```
NDK=$ANDROID_NDK
NDKABI=8
NDKVER=$NDK/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3
NDKP=$NDKVER/prebuilt/darwin-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-
NDKF="--sysroot $NDK/platforms/android-$NDKABI/arch-arm"

make HOST_CC="gcc -m32" CROSS=$NDKP TARGET_SYS=Linux TARGET_FLAGS="$NDKF"
```

My `$ANDROID_NDK` points to `r8b NDK`. But I also tried `r8` and `r7`, and I tried `gcc 4.6` with `r8b`. In all cases I get similar errors.

```
==== Building LuaJIT 2.0.0-beta9 ====
make -C src
ASM       lj_vm.o
lj_vm.s: Assembler messages:
lj_vm.s:5: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.private_extern'
lj_vm.s:8: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.private_extern'
lj_vm.s:25: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.private_extern'

…
```

Comment: Thx for this question. I had some werid output from Luajit build process when compiling for android on windows host. Your post made me rethink paths which I passed to Luajit CROSS and TARGET_FLAGS. I thought that from cygwin they should be /cygdrive/c as it turned out I was wrong - c:/ was the way gcc from android ndk wanted for --sysroot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to build LuaJIT 2.0.0-beta10 with no problems. The problem posted was when building beta9 or lower: looks like they patched whatever issue it was.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure but I think when you tried to build first time without `TARGET_SYS=Linux` you forgot clean `*.o` files in `src/host` directory after unsuccessful build.

For this reason you have seen a lot of errors like: `Error: unknown pseudo-op: '.private_extern'`

To clean all generated and builded files run `make clean`